# How do I encrypt a key for use with Linux's key retention service?

Tags: linux, encryption

In Linux, an "encrypted" key can be created for use with `keyctl` by executing a command like `keyctl add encrypted evm-key "new user:kmk-user 32" @u`. The content of the key, when exported to a file, might look like:

```
default user:kmk-user 32 2375725ad57798846a9bbd240de8906f006e66c03af53b1
b382dbbc55be2a44616e4959430436dc4f2a7a9659aa60bb4652aeb2120f149ed197c564
e024717c645972dcb82ab2dde83376d82b2e3c09ffc
```

If I already have a value that I want to use as my key, how do encrypt into a format like the above?